Movesense background communication
In my Maui application I'm using Kaasa.Mds library (which use movesense-device-lib) to communicate with movesense sensor. My question is: is there a solution to make this communication when application is in background? Some information is sending by callbacks for example:
await device.SubscribeAsync("/Meas/IMU6/208", [action]);
Thanks for help
I've made research about waking up the application for bluetooth callbacks, but without finding solution for MDS (android) and MDSWrapper (for iOS)
